# How do I implement a common interface for Django related object sets?

Tags: django, django-models, interface, dry

Here's the deal:

I got two db models, let's say `ShoppingCart` and `Order`. Following the DRY principle I'd like to extract some common props/methods into a shared interface `ItemContainer`.

Everything went fine till I came across the `_flush()` method which mainly performs a delete on a related object set.

```
class Order(models.Model, interface.ItemContainer):

# ...

def _flush(self):
    # ...
    self.orderitem_set.all().delete()
```

So the question is: how do I dynamically know wheter it is `orderitem_set` or `shoppingcartitem_set`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here are two Django snippets that should be exactly what you're looking for:

- [Model inheritance with content type and inheritance-aware manager](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/)
- [ParentModel and ChildManager for Model Inheritance](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1037/)

Second, you might want to re-think your design and switch to the django.contrib [content types framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes) which has a simple [`.model_class()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.model_class) method.  (The first snippet posted above also uses the content type framework).

Third, you *probably* don't want to use multiple inheritance in your model class.  It shouldn't be needed and I wouldn't be surprised if there were some obscure side affects.  Just have `interface.ItemContainer` inherit from `models.Model` and then `Order` inherit from only `interface.ItemContainer`.

Comment: You can actually do multiple inheritance like that and it works without a problem (so far as I can tell), but I would still probably inherit ItemContainer from Model (unless its an interface that can apply to non-Model objects).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the related_name argument of a ForeignKey, so if you want to make minimal changes to your design, you could just have ShoppingCartItem and OrderItem set the same related_name on their ForeignKeys to ShoppingCart and Order, respectively (something like "item_set"):

```
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='item_set')
```

and

```
cart = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingCart, related_name='item_set')
```