# Proper Child class selection

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django (and programming) in my free time.  It is fun but I am having an issue with how to logically make a distinction between two models that share a parent.

What I would like to do is have a form where I can enter a machine and a file to send it.  The issue I have is that I have two types of machines (they are RS-232 communication)  These machines have either hardware flow control or software flow control.

I have set a url /transmitProgram/ to take entered form data and send it to the proper place.  I do not know how to select the right machine settings.

OfficeMachine is a hardware flow controlled machine and GarageMachine is software flow controlled

I send in my form to send file 001 to OfficeMachine (how to know if OfficeMachine is software or hardware)

Models.py

```
class SerialMachine(models.Model):
    EVEN = 1
    ODD = 2
    NONE = 3
    PARITY_CHOICES = (
        (EVEN, "Even"),
        (ODD, "Odd"),
        (NONE, "None"),
    )

    machineName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    baudRate = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    parity = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=PARITY_CHOICES)
    dataBits = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
    stopBits = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
    carriageReturn = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lineFeed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    endProgramChar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    machineServer = models.ForeignKey('SerialPortServer')
    repository = models.ForeignKey('Repository')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.machineName

class HardwareFlowControlMachine(SerialMachine):
    """
    Represents all CNC machines that are to be connected for a hardware flow
    control connection
    """
    enableRTSCTS = models.BooleanField(default=False) # RTS/CTS Flow Control
    enableDSRDTR = models.BooleanField(default=True) # DSR/DTR Flow Control

class SoftwareFlowControlMachine(SerialMachine):
    """"
    Represents all CNC machines that are to be connected for a software flow
    control connection
    """
    xonChar = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, default=17)
    xoffChar = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, default=19)
```

My view takes the data from the form and calls a helper function to get the path and machine settings.

Helper.py

```
def getMachineSettings(machine):
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

    from src.apps.cnc.models import SoftwareFlowControlMachine, HardwareFlowControlMachine

    machineSettings = ""
    try:
        machineSettings = SoftwareFlowControlMachine.get(name_iexact='%s' % machine)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    if machineSettings == "":
        try:
            machineSettings = HardwareFlowControlMachine.get(name_iexact='%s' % machine)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
    return machineSettings
```

This just seems like a dumb way to do it though.  This post [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515145/how-do-i-implement-a-common-interface-for-django-related-object-sets) introduced me to the djangosnippets website.

I was looking at [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1037/) but I am pretty weak in seeing everything fit together.

Am I correct in understanding that if I add inherit ParentModel in my SerialMachine absract class and create a ChildManager that I could just say

```
machineSettings = SerialMachine.get(name_iexact'%s' % machine)
```

and from the fields in the inherited classes will be there for me?

Thanks a lot for help and info you can provide for me

Comment: Don't call it a "Helper".  Call it a "Factory".  Folks are more comfortable with the "Factory" design pattern; it makes the job explicit.  Helper can mean anything.  Factory means that it creates subclass objects.

Comment: Don't remember it.  Fix your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See InheritanceManager in [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils), maybe it will fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the grander scope of your needs, an third-party package such as @yedpodtrzitko suggest, may be necessary. However, this can be simply done without additional machinery by taking advantage of the way Django handles MTI (Multiple Table Inheritance). Each instance of `SerialMachine` will have an attribute named after whatever child class was used to create it. Based on this, you can get the child class from the parent by simply testing for the presence of the attribute:

```
class SerialMachine(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def child(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'hardwareflowcontrolmachine'):
            return self.hardwareflowcontrolmachine
        elif hasattr(self, 'softwareflowcontrolmachine'):
            return self.softwareflowcontrolmachine
        else:
            return None
```

Then, just use `machine.child` wherever you need the specific machine type. (You can of course change the name of the attribute to anything you like.

Comment: Thanks very much, this looks much more elegant than what I had tried